# Finding the maximum of two variable

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, maxima-minima

Question :

If $\sqrt x + \sqrt y = \sqrt {135}$ for $x,y \in Z_{\ge 0}$

Find $max ~(xy)$

---

My first approach :

suppose $a = \sqrt{x}$ , $b = \sqrt{y}$

$ ab = \left(xy\right)^\frac{1}{2}, ~ a+b = \left(135\right)^\frac{1}{2}$

usage of AM-GM , equality hold if (and only if ) $a=b$:

$$ 0 \le \sqrt{ab} \le \frac{a+b}{2}$$

$$ 0 \le \left(xy\right)^{\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2}= \frac{1}{4}} \le \frac{135^{\frac{1}{2}}}{2}$$

$$ max~(xy)  = \frac{135^2}{2^4}$$

---

My second approach:

$$\sqrt{y} = \sqrt{135}-\sqrt{x}$$

Square both sides :
$$ y = 135 -2\sqrt{135x}+x $$

Maximizing the function :

$$f(x) = (x)(135-2\sqrt{135x}+x)$$

$$f’(x) = \frac{d}{dx}(x)[135-2\sqrt{135x}+x] + [x] \frac{d}{dx}(135-2\sqrt{135x}+x) $$

$$ f’(x) = 135+2x-3\sqrt{135x}$$

Solving for critical points :

$$ 2x-3\sqrt{135x}+135 = 0$$

$$ x = \frac{135}{4} , x= {135}$$

$$  f \left(\frac{135}{4}\right) = \frac{135^2}{4^2} = \frac{135^2}{2^4} , ~~ f\left(135\right) = 0 $$

Hence,

$$ max~(xy) = \frac{135^2}{2^4}$$

---

Though both approaches gave the same answer, I still want to validate my approaches. Please guys if you could validate the solution

Comment: Note that $x,y\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: I would be surprised that there are any solutions to your equation...

Comment: $\sqrt x + \sqrt y = 3\sqrt{15}$. $xy$ is maximum when $x$ and $y$ are closest to each other (here they cannot be equal). In any case there are only couple of solutions to this and one of them is $x = 0$ or $y = 0$

Comment: @Saad thanks for the response, right.

Comment: @MathLover thanks for the response, but suppose $x,y > 0$ not restricted to integers only. Then can my working suffice to prove maximum ?

Comment: @joshua check @asher’s working seems correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y = 135 -2\sqrt{135x}+x$$
So $x=15k^2$ ( where $k$ is a non negative integer) because $135x$ is a perfect square
$$\sqrt{y} = \sqrt{135}-\sqrt{x}=(3-k)\sqrt{15}$$
$$\implies y=15(3-k)^2$$
(Note: $k\le3$ otherwise $\sqrt{y}$ will be negative)

So the general solution is $(x,y)=(15k^2,15(3-k)^2)$
$$\implies xy=225(3k-k^2)^2$$
$0\le k\le3$, so $(3k-k^2)^2$ is maximum when $k=1$ or $2$.
Therefore $\max(xy)=225\cdot4=900$

Comment: Hey @Asher2211 thanks for the response. Could you elaborate a bit on $x =15k^2$

Comment: @Gaurang $135x$ is a perfect square. $135x=9\times 15x=3^2\times 15x$, so $15x$ is a perfect square. Let $15x=m^2$, $15$ divides $m$ so we can write as $m=15k$. Now $x=\frac{m^2}{15}=15k^2$.

Comment: Thank you very much, understood all working. So, perfect square to get integers values only right?